# A key on my keyboard is not working!

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, delete

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Today I noticed that my <kbd>Delete</kbd> button is not working. I tried restart, but the problem persists. All other keys are working properly.

Why has this problem occurred and how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe just this key is damaged? Have you tried another keyboard or tried your keyboard on another system?

Comment: I am using a laptop, so it is not easy to change the keyboard. However, it is not probable that a key is damaged suddenly without any stress!

Comment: During the years i have used 3 laptops, all ended up with keyboard problems:) I suppose you will have an empty usb-port you could use for an external keyboard? And remember, when things are broken, before that, it worked well:)

Comment: The problem was a hardware problem with keyboard. And it is solve by cleaning the keyboard by air jet and hard-pressing not-working key many times!

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for posting this as an answer but the comments don't give enough space and mark-up to properly test whether your key still works or not.  If it works, I'll delete this answer and we'll go hunting for what is wrong in software.

**Remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is your friend!** That is the key combination to press to get back here so you can read the rest of the message...

OK?  Got that?  Have it on a Post-It note? **;-)**

Good! Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and you will se a terminal (a *real* terminal, not `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` that you've used until now...)

Log in by typing your user name and password (no stars or password will be echoed, this is 1970s technology after all) and once you're logged in type the following command:

```
showkey --scancodes
```

Now lightly press and release the <kbd>Esc</kbd> the key that's not working and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key...  Then do what you do best for 10 seconds...

If you have a minimum of 6 lines on your screen, you're in luck: you don't have a hardware problem; your keyboard still works and should write down the output on a Post-It and leave a comment below with the output...  (no copy-paste back in the '70s!!!  And now that I think of it: no Post-Its either!)

Comment: Every key shows a code, but "Del" key! If i press it nothing occurs. It seems that this a hardware problem. But why this occurred?

Comment: As to the "why", I can only guess and here are a few: "Did the cat pee on your keyboard?  Is there a crumb stuck below the [Del] key? When was the last time you vacuum cleaned your keyboard? Do you have kids?"  **;-)**

Comment: Non of those! this occurred during I was working with my laptop!

Comment: In that case, I would try to vacuum clean my keyboard first and if that doesn't help, go to the laptop manufacturer/store for a service repair and ask the technician why it broke...  I'm sorry to say, but this is a software Q&A site, hardware still has to be repaired by qualified technicians.  **;-)**

Comment: I'm not sure this still works in 18.04. It just creates a blackscreen with no apparent exit strategy available.

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu any more so ask a question how to go to a TTY in 18.x, refer to this question and an editor will take care of it. @42-

Comment: When I hold Esc down I get a lot of `0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 ` until I release the Esc key they I see `0x81` just once. Interesting.